# How to handle custom response code in Retrofit 2 android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a Backend service that returns a success response like this:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "response_code":600,
    "result": {
        "id":103,
        "name":"Khalid",
        "email":"kha.taha92@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

and returns the fail response like this:

```
{
    "status":"fail",
    "response_code":605,
    "result": "Something went wrong"
}
```

And both responses are 200 (success) 
What I need is to handle the 605 as an error not as a success response.

Comment: Handling a custom property of a `JSON` string response is something that your logic should take care of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onResponse`, just test on the code result.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<YourModel> call, Response<YourModel> response) {
    if (response.code() == 600) {
       // Do success stuff
    } else if (response.code() == 605){
       // Handle error response 
    }
}
```

Comment: At least add a wrapper `if (response.isSuccessfull()){ ... }` and `response.code()` is not assigned with the `response_code` property of the JSON string

Comment: not this what I need,
I need the response printed in the log to be 600 or 605 instead of 200